# why timezone_name_from_abbr fetching wrong result?

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

I face weird problem on converting offset to timezone name.
I use follwing code to convert offset to timezone.

```
$timezoneOffset = "+05:30";
echo $timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("",$timezoneOffset*3600,0);
```

> output: Asia/Karachi
>
> Expected output: Asia/Kolkata

To check offset i use

```
$timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
$time = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$timezoneOffset = $time->format('P');  //output:  +05:30

$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("",$timezoneOffset*3600,0);
echo $timezone_name;exit;
```

still the output is `Asia/Karachi`

So what is the problem? what should i do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you understand the implications of this.  There are plenty of different time zones that share the same offset, and some that share the same abbreviation as well.  `timezone_name_from_abbr` just returns the *first match* of any possible results.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the `$gmtOffset` parameter (Offset from GMT in seconds) is incorrect.

In PHP, `"+05:30" * 3600` gives `18000` as the result. This is because the string is converted to the integer `5` and then multiplied.  This of course means that you're calling `timezone_name_from_abbr()` with an offset of `300` minutes rather than your expected `330` minutes, leading to the "wrong" timezone name being returned.

If you wish to keep your existing `$timezoneOffset` string, the following can be used to convert to the timezone offset in seconds.

```
$timezoneOffset = "+05:30";
$offsetSeconds = DateTime::createFromFormat('P', $timezoneOffset)->format('Z');
```

Comment: i change offset to `5.5` and it is solved. Thank you very much.